# No valid crumb was included in the request - Jenkins on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, http-status-code-403, git-push, gitbucket

I installed Jenkins 2.46.2 on Windows Server 2012 and integrated it with GitBucket.

I am trying the trigger the build when a change is pushed to GitBucket.

I tried to add a webhook but I get this error:

> Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 403
>
> Problem accessing
>   /jenkins/gitbucket-webhook/. Reason:
>
> ```
>  No valid crumb was included
> in the request
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Powered by
>   Jetty://*
>
> ---

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

**obtain crumb**

```
$ wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user yourUserName --password yourPassword--output-document - 'http://myJenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

Now Run Jenkins Job

`$ curl -I -X POST http://yourUserName:yourPassword@myJenkins:8080/job/JOBName/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb:44e7038af70da95a47403c3bed5q10f8`"

HTTP/1.1 201 Created Date: Fri, 28 July 2017 09:15:45 GMT X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Location: http://myJenkins:8080/queue/item/17/ Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that I left the jenkins window unattended for some time. Once I navigated to the jenkins root I was prompted to sign in again and was able to configure the job with git. I also enabled `AUTO REFRESH` in jenkins which will likely prevent this in the future.